# How do you calculate a test value that only effects your grade by a certain percentage?

Tags: percentages, calculator

My teacher has talked about how a certain test will only effect twenty percent of your final mark, how do you calculate this?

Say my current total mark is 95%, I got a test score of 70%, but the test only accounted for 20% of my final mark.

Comment: It sounds like your teacher is talking about computing the "final mark" as a weighted average of the various grading components.  Your Question is not terribly clear about what you mean to calculate.  Calculating the "final mark" is pretty straightforward, given the component grades and their relative weights.

Comment: Ya I meant a final mark, calculating a weighted average seems rather easy on google. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this would be an opportunity for you to compose an Answer to your own Question, providing a bit more of the detailing you found with Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I found my answer.

The test makes up twenty percent of my mark and I got seventy percent then I write

> 70 * .2 = 14

My current mark(95%) takes up the leftover eighty percent so

```
95 * .8 = 76
```

Then, I add them together to get my final mark of 90